# Run/Debug launch shortcut

Tags: eclipse-plugin, view, eclipse-rcp, launch

Within the project explorer in eclipse, the context menu bars "Debug as" and "Run as" appear allowing to launch in debug/run mode.
I have created a new view (Replacement to Project Explorer view) and these context menu bars don't appear.
I couldn't find what I should add to the plugin.xml in order to add these context menu bars also to my new view.

Could anyone help ?

Comment: For which objects/selection do you want those sub-menus to be available?

Comment: As @MarttiKäärik asked, what types are the objects are you exposing in your view?  Did you add the `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchActionConstants.MB_ADDITIONS` group marker to your view's context menu?

Answer (score 0):

Those menu items are extracted with [Common Navigator Framework](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/cnf.htm). Consider using [CommonViewer](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/navigator/CommonViewer.html) for them to reappear.